# Why window.open displays a blank screen in a desktop PWA (looks obfuscated)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, desktop, progressive-web-apps

On an installed Desktop PWA, since Chrome 73 (on MacOS) when I do a `window.open()` on a click event with a regular URL, the page loads fully but the window is blank.

It looks obfuscated but there's no overlay tag of anything visible (everything is OK in the devtools's console and network tabs)

I tried with the default Chrome theme, both with Mojave's dark an light mode.

The HTML markup:

```
<a href="https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/" data-index="2" data-category="svg" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="data-app-button">
  <span class="app-name">SVGOMG</span>
</a>
```

The JavaScript:

```
// clicks
document.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function (event) {
      if (event.target.closest("[data-app-index]")) {
        let appID = event.target.closest("[data-app-index]").getAttribute("data-app-index");
        return openApp(appID);
      }
    },
    false
);


// openApp() - a regular window.open()
const openApp = appID => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // get app options
    let appOptions = State.appList[appID];
    appOptions.window = appOptions.window || {};

    // merge with defaults
    let defaultWindow = State.getDefaultWindow;
    let options = Object.assign({}, defaultWindow, appOptions.window);

    // center window
    options.left = screen.width / 2 - options.width / 2;
    options.top = screen.height / 2 - options.height / 2;

    // translate to window.open args
    let args = [];
    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(options)) args.push(`${key}=${val}`);
    args = args.join(",");

    // open app
    return window.open(appOptions.url, appOptions.name, args);
};
```

Before updating to Chrome 73 everything worked as expected: the `window.open()` function displayed the web page correctly.

Now the window opens but nothing is visible.

[image: window.open]

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found the solution: I noticed that right after the window was open, the parent window (PWA) got the focus back. So it behaved like a pop-under. As pop-under are a really bad/malicious practice I think Chrome is blocking the child popup window.

So I removed the return statement on the event callback:

```
// I changed this:
return openApp(appID);

// to this:
openApp(appID);
```

It seems that the parent window do not steal the focus anymore and the popup content is displayed correctly.